# Matching ple in middle of word and replacing with letter p

Tags: replace

The following function replaces character sequences for the cases of prefixes and suffixes.  I would also like to handle the case of matches that occur medially within a word (e.g. insert `p' for occurrence of` ple'), meaning that the word contains at least a single character on either side of the character sequence `ple'.

Would like to use

```
    (defun shorten-word ()
      "Shortens a word according to specific rules."
    
      (interactive)
    
      (let* ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word))
         (s (car bounds))
         (case-fold-search nil)
         (e (make-marker))
         (p (point-marker)))
    
        (when s
          (set-marker e (cdr bounds))
          (goto-char s)
          (cond

             ((search-forward-regexp
                 (concat  "\\<"
                 (regexp-opt '("cog" "col" "com" "con" "cor" "cum" "coun")))
                 (cdr bounds)
                 t)
    
            (replace-match "k"))
      
           ;;-----------------------------------------------
           ;; Insert `l' for words with final
           ;; `ley', `ily', and `ly'.  
           ((search-forward-regexp
            (concat (regexp-opt '("ley" "ily" "ly")) "\\>")
               (cdr bounds))
    
            (replace-match "l"))
        
           ;;-----------------------------------------------
           ;; Insert letter `p' for median `ple'.

            ((save-excursion
                (re-search-forward "ple" e t))
                (replace-match "p"))
           
           ;;-----------------------------------------------
           (t nil))
    
          (goto-char p))
        (set-marker e nil)
        (set-marker p nil)))
```

Comment: At least two issues: (1) this errors if there are no matches for the "ily" things---add an argument `t` at the end of the `search-forward-regexp` form. (2) this send "please" to "pase" because you have not checked for mid-word in the final search.

Comment: What can be a solution to a mid-word search?

Comment: You already have a solution for the mid-word issue: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73073/matching-character-sequences-medially-in-words

Comment: BTW, `search-forward-regexp` is an alias for `re-search-forward`: you should use one or the other but not both - it is less confusing that way.

Comment: Implementation: all the methods you have rely on a regex and that is independent of the implementation.

Comment: **"any comments for improvements would be appreciated"** is not a question. Should be closed.

Comment: @NickD Thank you for pointing out the alias detail.  Ass is well then.  I would be grateful if you can write a quick answer, and I can accept and close the question.

Comment: I've provided an answer of sorts, but that is not necessary for the question to be closed: you can always delete it. Or people can vote to close it (as I have). in its current form, it's almost certainly not going to prove useful to anybody in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer is impossible (*any answer* is impossible). Here's a small change to the above that does approximately what you want:

```el
...
(cond

             ((search-forward-regexp
                 (concat  "\\<"
                 (regexp-opt '("cog" "col" "com" "con" "cor" "cum" "coun")))
                 (cdr bounds)
                 t)
    
            (replace-match "k"))
      
           ;;-----------------------------------------------
           ;; Insert `l' for words with final
           ;; `ley', `ily', and `ly'.  
           ((search-forward-regexp
            (concat (regexp-opt '("ley" "ily" "ly")) "\\>")
               (cdr bounds) t)
    
            (replace-match "l"))
        
           ;;-----------------------------------------------
           ;; Insert letter `p' for median `ple'.
           ((search-forward-regexp "\\w\\(ple\\)\\w" (cdr bounds) t)
            (replace-match "p" nil nil nil 1))

 
           ;;-----------------------------------------------
           (t nil))
    
...
```

The regexp `"\\w\\(ple\\)\\w"` uses grouping to remember that `ple` was the match of the first (and only) parenthesized subexpression and that fact is used in `(replace-match "p" nil nil nil 1)` to replace *only* that part (the final 1 says so) with `p`. Do `C-h f replace-match` for the details.

But your problem is woefully underspecified. What do you want to happen on `completely`? Should it become `kpletely`, `completel`, `kpletl`, `comptely`, `comptel`, `kptely` or `kptel`? The function does the first one, but it's not clear what you want it to do. Since we don't know where you are trying to go, all we can do is fix the most egregious problems and hope that it might somehow help.

Our quandary is: Do we answer a seemingly endless stream of questions, some  of which may be related but all slightly different (like the twisty little passages of the old "Adventure" game), about all sorts of problems that may or not be relevant to anything? Do we just ignore you and hope you go away? Or do we do something in-between to try to help you to understand *why* your questions are impossible to answer? I think most of us have gone some way in the third direction: I think I've tried to do that to the extent possible, but the problem is that I'm not seeing much progress and I cannot hold much hope that your questions will become better in the future. I'm certainly not willing on a regular basis to expend as much time as I have expended on this answer alone, let alone on multiple questions every day.

I am sorry to have to say this, but unless I see *serious* improvement, I don't think I'll be answering any questions of yours in the future. I have too many other things to do and not enough time to do them, so I have to prioritize where my time is spent - as do we all.